# Difference between free and gratis?

Tags: word-difference

When reading questions and answers on different stack exchange sites related to software, there seems to be a difference between *free* and *gratis*.

Could you please elaborate on what the difference between these two terms are?

And is *gratis* a commonly used term in English?

Comment: I've hardly ever heard gratis in everyday speech: Here's some evidence from Ngrams: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gratis%2C+free&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgratis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfree%3B%2Cc0. In answer to your question, "gratis" would mean "free of charge"

Comment: Still that is the most common tag at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/, not free...

Comment: I was answering your second question - "is it commonly used in english"

Comment: I know the general meaning,  but wondering about the difference of these terms, if any.  In Norwegian we also have gratis as a word,  and use that instead of the translation of free, when talking about something being free of charge. But that is a digression.

Comment: See also [this](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/2516/32), which has the third most upvotes of any question on ELL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like many other English words, the word "free" has several overlapping meanings, and two of those meanings turn out to be problematic when discussing software. In particular, "this software is free" could mean:

- free as in **free beer**: "this software *costs no money* to use"; or
- free as in **free speech**: "this software *has few or no restrictions* on how it may be used"

To remove the ambiguity, some people write "gratis software" to mean the first kind (costs no money), and "free software" to mean the second kind (has few or no restrictions).

Some examples:

- **Neither gratis nor free software:** Most commercial software falls into this category. If you want Microsoft Office, you must both pay money for it, and agree to a lot of restrictions on how you can use the software. For example, you are not allowed to edit the internal workings of Microsoft Office to make it behave differently, fix a bug, et cetera.
- **Gratis, but not free software:** Adobe Reader is available without charge, but if you want to use it you must agree to a number of restrictions on how you use it. For example, you are allowed to run the software. But you are not allowed to package it up and sell it as something else to another person.
- **Free and gratis software:** The [Blender Game Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender_Game_Engine) is the building block of many games. You can use Blender at no charge, and you are only minimally restricted in how you use Blender or what you do with it.

Gratis is not otherwise an everyday word in English, outside of specialized distinctions like this one.

Comment: What kind of restrictions are we talking about here?

Comment: For example, the software might permit you to _run_ it, but **not** to _modify_ it (change how it works), _redistribute_ it (give it to other people), _sell_ it (charge other people money), etc.

Comment: Do you imply that gratis software is possible to resell? That sounds wrong...

Comment: No, I'm saying that whether software is _gratis_ is **independent** of whether it's _unencumbered by restrictions_.

Comment: In other words, gratis refers *only*  to the price aspect, whilst free could talk about other things?

Comment: Correct. In this context, _gratis_ refers only to whether software costs money or not. _Free_ refers to whether it has restrictions on how you can use it.

Comment: Some people use *libre* to refer to software without restrictions, to further distinguish between free-as-in-price and free-as-in-freedom.

Comment: @JohnFeminella +1'd